# tomcat 8 - webapp folder gets deleted even when autodeploy is off

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

for some reason my webapp folder got deleted out of the blue with **auto-deploy=of**f.

I checked the logs and i saw large number of exceptions and errors but no crash in my application.
after restarting tomcat webapp folder was created empty.
I had to redeploy my apps.

Any reasons for tomcat to delete webapp folder?

Comment: I'd imagine the reasons are related to the large number of exceptions and errors you're getting.

Comment: I think so too but i could not find anywhere to define this failsafe mechanism

Comment: I'd concentrate on getting rid of the errors (which you don't describe in any way) first, and seeing if the behaviour persists.